# Backup wordpress installation on shared hosting

Tags: backup

I have a wordpress website on a shared hosting. For redundancy reasons, I want to have a copy of the site on another shared hosting, so that if the first one is down, the traffic can be redirected to the other one.

Asking this question in wordpress section because most of the challenges are wordpress specific than server specific. Those are:

- Wordpress works only on one domain name, so how can I access the 2nd installation when DNS is pointing to the first one? I don't want to load balance but more of a fallover.
- What's the best way to sync files and DB across shared hosting? Any wordpress plugins that can do this seamlessly every time a new post is published?

Answer (score 0):

DNS establishes which IP address domain is pointing to. Load balancers are used precisely because it work like that and there needs to be single point of entry before load can be spread or redirected to multiple servers.

Simply put shared hosting is not engineered or marketed for high reliability, that is whole other level of technical means and costs.